# VB Command request

Tags: vb.net, command, cursor

WORD 2019 
Developer 
small sub program  / busy cursor question

*Given a small subprogram*

```
Sub ABC()

    Etc..

End Sub
```

"End Sub" is not stopping the compiler immediately. The busy cursor is still looking for something and I am not sure what it is busy doing.
The program completes the requested tasks I have written however after it generates the output, the small "busy cursor " (spinning blue circle) appears and delays the start of the new input.  I have tried the "STOP" command and it works however it takes the screen back to the debugger which I do not need. I have tried the "Exit"  and " Exit Sub" commands and the busy cursor keeps appearing even after the program compiles correctly without errors.  Is there another command to cause the immediate stop of the busy cursor so the next request for data output can be entered without the delay caused via the busy cursor?  I am not sure what the compiler is still checking for ?

I tried modifying the iteration counter to 1 however the busy cursor still delays my next entry. Is there another command (other than the STOP command) which will immediately cause the compiler to stop and allow for the next entry?  It is not an infinite loop and there are  no errors. The small sub program completes its tasks very quickly however the busy cursor delays the next entry. It eventually stops however I do not know what it is busy checking for else what task(s) it is completing. The STOP command  ,as I mention, works, however I do not wish for the next step to be the debugger because there is/are no error(s).

"
Oct 10, 2018 · In Excel 2007, go to Office button > Excel options > Formulas > Iteration area. In Excel 2003 and earlier, go to Menu > Tools > Options > Calculation. Enabling iterative calculations will bring up two additional inputs in the same menu: Maximum Iterations determines how many times Excel is to recalculate the workbook, Maximum Change determines the maximum difference between values of iterative …

From

The high-level language that you feed the compiler is also known as source code, and the machine language translation it  generates is called object code. Object code, or sometimes object module, is what a computer compiler produces. Traditionally, the output of the compilation has been called object code or sometimes an object module.

Comment: `End Sub`, `Exit Sub` etc. only have an effect at run time, not at compile time. At compile time they are just a syntax element.

Comment: How about you show us some **code** instead of `Etc..`?...then we might be able to help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: "It is not an infinite loop"  What loop are you talking about? I don't see any loop.

Comment: When the `Sub ABC() reaches End Sub it returns to the calling code. There might be code there or up the call stack that is slowing down the code.

Answer (score 0):

Examples as follows:

I have numerous small sub programs in a row which are controlled via command buttons(controls-Visual Basic Developer)) from an excel page. So when I press a command control it should find the sub program linked to the command control ,complete the tasks, and then exit so I can enter/ else press another command control(button).

The problem is when the task in the small sub program is complete the small spinning blue circle appears and lingers too long. Either the End Sub else Exit Sub command are not functioning correctly else there is another statement to exit the sub program immediately and allow the individual pressing the commands to continue to enter another command else stop.

At the End Sub I do not want to see the blue spinning circle the "busy cursor",it is not busy, it has completed the tasks inside the Small Sub Programs.

The busy cursor lingers after the tasks are completed and there are no errors. Please note all variables are defined. The example below is partial.

### All Dims are entered etc..

' 1rst sub program linked to a command control(button) comment

Sub tellOperator(ByVal task As String)
  Dim stamp As Date
  stamp = TimeOfDay()
  MsgBox("Starting " & task & " at " & CStr(stamp))
End Sub

' 2nd sub program linked to a command control(button) comment

Imports System

Public Module Hello
   Public Sub Main(  )
      Console.WriteLine("hello, world")
   End Sub
End Module

Sub TestSub()
    MsgBox "Code in TestSub()"
End Sub

' 3rd sub program linked to a command control(button) comment

Private Sub Form_Load()
    MsgBox "Code in Form_Load()"
    TestSub
    MsgBox "Back in Form_Load()"
End Sub